# Missing required parameter: redirect_uri with passport-google-oauth

Tags: node.js, express, google-oauth, passport-google-oauth

Using `passport-google-oauth: "0.2.0"` in my MEAN Stack application (found here: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth). When I run the application and attempt to sign in with a Google API this error is returned

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: invalid_request
>
> Missing required parameter: redirect_uri
>
> Request Details 
>   scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
>   response_type=code 
>   redirect_uri=
>   client_id=xxxx-xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com

The redirect param is here
`passport-init.js`

> var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
>
> var GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = "xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
>   var GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxx";
>
> passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
>   clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
>   clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
>   callbackUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google/oauth2callback"  },
>   function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){
>       done(null,profile); } ));

The routes are here `authenticate.js`

> router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', 
>   { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login']}), 
>   function (req, res){ });
>
> router.get('/google/oauth2callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
>   successRedirect: '/auth/success', failureRedirect: '/auth/failure'  })
>   , function (req, res) {res.redirect('/');} );

I am sure I am missing something simple, but I don't know what to add in this question that will give you the best information. Please ask and I will do my best to answer you. This is what feels like the pertinent data.

Funny thing is if I add the callbackUrl manually then everything works great. I can reach the Google API fine. Then I am given the choice to "allow" or "deny" the request.

Comment: I'm going to abandon this approach and try https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/ instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When defining the GoogleStrategy, the JSON key should be callbackURL instead of callbackUrl (i.e., capital URL). Had this 'issue' as well ;-)

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I knew I was missing something. I never thought it was something so simple.

Comment: for me i had callBackURL, had to make as you said 'callbackURL'

Answer (score 1):

I have a working example using the same strategy. Since I don't get this error, can't pinpoint what the problem is, but I wanted to suggest you check the following:

- add to your google strategy creation (new GoogleStrategy({...})) the scope:

  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
- Make sure your google api is configured properly in the [dev api console](https://console.developers.google.com). Specifically:

  1. Under APIs and auth | Credentials | OAuth consent screen - all the required url.
  2. Under APIs and auth | Credentials - look for your web api client and see you authorized all the relevant URIs. The auth will not work if the call is from or the redirection is to a page that was not listed in this section.

Comment: That didn't work. Thanks for the suggestions but I still get an empty redirect_uri field. I assume there is somewhere in my server code that is missing the redirect_uri. The rest of the code in the error is coming from my code. I can manually insert the ?missing? redirect_uri and the request continues to process like normal.

Comment: You can dig into the module. search for the specific string and see where it happens. All the modules are nested in your node_modules directory

Answer (score 1):

I use something like that-
 1. Make sure that's URL and not uri.
 2. Make sure the callback URL you registered is same as the one you are requesting for.

---

```js
var passport = require('passport');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

// Use the GoogleStrategy within Passport.
//   Strategies in Passport require a `verify` function, which accept
//   credentials (in this case, an accessToken, refreshToken, and Google
//   profile), and invoke a callback with a user object.
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/google/callback"
    //should be same as the one you registered in credentials.
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
       User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
         return done(err, user);
       });
  }
));
```

---

P.S:my first one on stackoverflow. please ignore mistakes and help me in improving.

Answer (score 0):

My issue occuors in authenticate  with WSL. This error bellow is presented:

[error issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzXux.png)

To solved , utilize the command `gcloud init --console-only` in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue to. in my nestJs Application. I solved it by changing the CallbackURL from "callbackUrl" to "callbackURL"  URL all caps