# Getting Missing required parameter: scope Passport.js, express

Tags: node.js, express, google-oauth, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

Im using Passport.js with express in my app to login with Google Oauth. But when i try to sign in, i get the following error: `invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing authority: http:localhost:3000/google/callback` from which when i access `localhost:3000/google/callback`, i get `Missing required parameter: scope`. The relevant code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
require("dotenv").config();
require("./passport-setup")

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.get('/success', (req, res) => {
  res.render("/profile.html")
})

app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: 'email' }));
app.get('/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/failed' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/success');
  }
);
```

passport config(relevant code):

```js
const passport = require("passport");

const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth2").Strategy

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.CALLBACK_URL,
    passReqToCallback: true
},function(request,accessToken,refreshToken,profile,done){
    console.log(profile)
    return done(null, profile)
}

))
```

PS: I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924963/missing-required-parameter-redirect-uri-with-passport-google-oauth) but i don't know what he means by 'JSON key'. Maybe the API updated.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

---

## EDIT

The callback url I provided to google was not matching my `app.get`. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My callback URL was `http:localhost:3000/google/callback`

Setting it to `/gooogle/callback` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

> PS: I found this **answer** but i don't know what he means by 'JSON
> key' - the person referred to your `GoogleStrategy` which is **A JSON
> object** contains zero, one, or more **key-value** pairs.

/* SECURE COOKIES TRUE MADE GOOGLE SIGN IN / SIGNUP WORK */

I was getting an error when trying to Sign in/up with Google account: `Missing required parameter: scope` and the following lines of code added **before** `app.use(passport.initialize());` made it work!

```
if (app.get("env") === "production") {
    app.set("trust proxy", 1);
    session.cookie.secure = true;
}
```

You might have to implement `express-session` to make this work (check the npm website for docs on how to use) but simply declare at the top:

```
      const session = require("express-session");
```

**before** `app.use(passport.initialize())` add this lines:

```
      app.use(
         session({
            secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
            resave: false,
            saveUninitialized: false,
            cookie: {},
         })
      );
```

Comment: Oh okay, gotcha. I haven't been into programming for a while so i've forgotten everything. But as far as i can recall, i did all of the stuff beforehand and its just that i made a stupid mistake of not using the correct callback routes.