# How to avoid daily login to GCP as "gcloud auth login" from terminal

Tags: google-cloud-platform

By Using "Google Cloud SDK 431.0.0", it is required for me to login daily with '''gcloud auth login'''. Is there a way to avoid this behaviour and automate this process for an indidual account not a service account.

Comment: This may have been answered from this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71561730/authorizing-client-libraries-without-access-to-a-web-browser-gcloud-auth-appli)

Comment: I never noticed that. Is it your personal computer? Do you know if there is a daily cleanup in your data everyday?

Comment: Nope, not a personal one and no cleanup running on this (zsh)

Comment: @JamesS : It has solutions with depricated flags, even its working for now, may not be a permanent solution for future use.

Comment: This sounds like a policy in the organization in case you're using your organizational account